# Is my implement of the correctness of Bellman-Ford algorithm wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph, bellman-ford

I am following this tutorial: [Bellman-Ford Algorithm by Jessica Su](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture14.pdf) and implemented the Algorithm 2
[image]

as follows:

```
def negative_cycle(adj, cost):
    """
    detect negative cycle in a graph
    reference: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture14.pdf
    param adj: list of list, index represent nodes, and values the edges starting from them
    param cost: list of list, index represent nodes, and values the corresponding weights of edges
    return 0 or 1: 1 represents that there is at least 1 negative cycle in the graph
    >>> negative_cycle([[1], [2], [0], [0]], [[-5], [2], [1], [2]])
    1
    >>> negative_cycle([[1], [2], [3], [0]], [[2], [3], [1], [2]])
    0
    >>> negative_cycle([[1, 3], [2], [], [2]], [[3, 7], [4], [], [5]])
    0
    """
    vertex_num = len(adj)
    memorization_table = np.matrix(np.ones((vertex_num, vertex_num)) * np.inf)
    memorization_table[:, 0] = 0.0

    for i in range(1, vertex_num):
        for u in range(0, vertex_num):
            for j, v in enumerate(adj[u]):
                memorization_table[i, v] = min(memorization_table[i-1, v], memorization_table[i-1, u]+cost[u][j])

    for u in range(0, vertex_num):
        for j, v in enumerate(adj[u]):
            if memorization_table[i, v] > memorization_table[i-1, u]+cost[u][j]:
                return 1
    return 0
```

The complete code is [here](https://gist.github.com/eduOS/bbb70dab8244e749202ecef96e4a97e1).

The snippet failed the last test case where the graph is like this:

[image]

In that case, the update mechanism cannot guarantee that `memorization_table[i]` saved the smallest value since there are two paths and they are not compared.

Hence I wonder if the pseudo-code is wrong or my implementation is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm's pseudo code in the lecture notes has a mistake in this line:

← min{<sub>−1</sub>[], <sub>−1</sub>[] + (,)} // update estimate of v

This would make the value of  only dependent on the last visited edge (,). The effect on  of any previously visited edge to  would be overwritten.

Instead, this line should read:

← min{[], <sub>−1</sub>[] + (,)} // update estimate of v

This way the value of  becomes the minimum of all <sub>−1</sub>[] + (,)